# Incomplete phpmyadmin issue in xampp

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

phpmyadmin is not showing many fields all of the sudden. For example

Every table of DB in phpmyadmin is not showing primary key column to user, although column is present.

[image]

As you can see, heading of table is showing up but from values (td part) of table, one column missing (id). Hence "created_at" column showing without value column coz everything switched to left coz of missing id column in value fields.

Here is the table structure of the same table which showing primary key column. In other words, it hides first column.

[image]

Same happens when I call DB table data on admin panel's datatable. There also one column doesn't show up.

Also when I click on insert tab to add data in table fields via phpmyadmin, then no fields show up where I can add my values. Here is how

[image]

Same happens when I click on edit row of table.

It's been very long since I am facing this issue with xampp phpmyadmin.

I tried to re-install the xampp but even re-installing didn't solve the issue. Feeling totally helpless here. I have no idea what to do next to resolve it.